# How to prove that $(\sqrt{3} + 1)b/2 < a < 1 + (\sqrt{3} + 1)b/2$?

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation, examples-counterexamples, quadratics

I'm starting with the assumption that $a, b > 0$, and $$\frac{a - 1}{a + b - 1} \cdot \frac{a}{a + b} = \frac{1}{3}$$
I am trying to show that $$(\sqrt{3} + 1)b/2 < a < 1 + (\sqrt{3} + 1)b/2.$$

Since $$\frac{a - 1}{a + b - 1} < \frac{a}{a + b}$$ I can write that $$\left(\frac{a - 1}{a + b - 1}\right)^2 < \frac{1}{3} < \left(\frac{a}{a + b}\right)^2$$
so $$\frac{a - 1}{a + b - 1} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} < \frac{a}{a + b}$$
If I write $$\frac{a - 1}{a + b - 1} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} < \frac{a}{a + b} < \frac{a}{a + b - 1}$$
I can derive the worse bound $(\sqrt{3} + 1)(b - 1)/2 < a < (\sqrt{3} + 1)(b + 2)/2$. If I could have a hint on how I can derive the one stated in the question, that would be much appreciated. And, if possible, what are some general strategies I should consider when trying to solve these kinds of problems?

Thank you!

Edit: I got this from Probability, Random Variables, and Stochastic Processes by Papoulis. The problem is the following -
[image: problem]

If we assume that $a$ and $b$ must be integers greater than or equal to 1 does this resolve the problem with the bound?

Comment: my thought: let $x=a/b$ and write the given identity as a quadratic equation in $x$, then solve it to find the range of $x$. I'm not at home so can't do the explicit calculations. It may worth your try.

Comment: If $a=1/11$ and $b=4/11$, the equation holds but the claimed lower bound fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition gives:
$$2a^2-2a(b+1)-b^2+b=0,$$ which gives
$$a=\frac{b+1+\sqrt{3b^2+1}}{2}$$ or
$$a=\frac{b+1-\sqrt{3b^2+1}}{2}.$$
In the first case we need to prove that
$$\frac{(1+\sqrt3)b}{2}<\frac{b+1+\sqrt{3b^2+1}}{2}<1+\frac{(1+\sqrt3)b}{2}$$ or
$$\sqrt3b<1+\sqrt{1+3b^2}<2+\sqrt3b,$$ which is obvious.

In the second case we need $$\frac{b+1-\sqrt{3b^2+1}}{2}>0,$$ which gives $$0<b<1.$$
Can you end it now?

I got that there is a problem with $$\frac{(1+\sqrt3)b}{2}<\frac{b+1-\sqrt{3b^2+1}}{2},$$ which is wrong for $b\rightarrow1^-.$

Because in this case we need to prove that:
$$\frac{1+\sqrt3}{2}\leq\frac{2-2}{2},$$ which is wrong.

If $a\geq1$ and $b\geq1$ so the second case is impossible because the second root is negative and we are done!

Comment: I just edited my post -- I think we have to assume that $a, b \geq 1$ and are integers, which removes the second case.

Comment: @TheProofisTrivium Yes, of course, and we proved our inequality.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it. If you don't mind, how can you see that the second inequality fails as $b$ approaches 1 from below?

Comment: @TheProofisTrivium For $a\geq1$ and $b\geq1$ we don't need a second case, because in the quadratic equation on $a$, which I wrote $b^2-b\leq0,$ which by the Viete's theorem gives that the second root is not positive, which is impossible because $a\geq1.$ While for the positive root our inequality is proven.

Comment: Sure, I understand that the second case is unnecessary, but I was just curious why that second inequality (say, if we only have that $a,b \geq 0$) doesn’t hold as b approaches 1. Thanks again! Oops, this is me just on a different account.

Comment: Do you mean to explain, why where I wrote "which is obvious",  it's indeed obvious?

Comment: Ah no, if you could explain “got that there is a problem with ... which is wrong for”

Comment: @yonatano I added something. See now.